# Как переместить блок по блоку

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Имеем структуру html

```
<div>
    <div class="1"></div>
    <div class="2"></div>
    <div class="3"></div>
    <div class="4"></div>
    <div class="5"></div>
</div>
```

нужно что бы блок 3 переместился с 3ей позиции на первую без перезагрузки. При этом затронул только блок 1 и 2 а блок 4 и 5 остались неподвижными jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
function move3() {
  $(".parent .3").parent().prepend($(".parent .3"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="1">1</div>
  <div class="2">2</div>
  <div class="3">3</div>
  <div class="4">4</div>
  <div class="5">5</div>
</div>

<button onclick="move3()">Move</button>
```